# Why Double data type works here

Tags: c++, c, algorithm

I am doing a [problem](http://uva.onlinejudge.org/index.php?option=com_onlinejudge&Itemid=8&category=99&page=show_problem&problem=49) on UVa. The problem statement is  as follows:

We have to find nth root of a number p, and there exists an integer k such that k^n=p. So basically we have to find integer k.

Constraints:

**p<10^101**, n<200, k<10^9. 
All variables are integers and positive.

The AC solution to the problem in c simply calculates,

```
pow(p,1/n);
```

i know double can hold data upto e308, but as far as i know upto a precision of 15 decimal places.

So my question is why the solution above works, can't there be any precision error?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

the number 10^101 looks very big. if n were 2 you could not store k anywhere.

but if you look at the other constraints - k is limited to 10^9. that takes 30 bits of an unsigned type. the mantissa of a double can easily hold that.

Comment: but can p be stored accurately?

Comment: no. you loose precision on p. but that is irrelevant when you shrink it to k<10^9.

Comment: ok, i am getting somewhere close, but now can you elaborate why the accuracy of p doesn't matter when we shrink it to 10^9.

Comment: say we have 999999. unfortunately we loose precision and have 999000. now we divide by 999 and get 100 (exact) instead of 100.1 which is pointless if you round to integer.

Answer (score 0):

Hint: how many decimal places are required by the problem statement?

Comment: no decimal places, just integer, but when we enter p as a double, can double store it completely? Because if p has 10^100 digits it can't store it accurately( i guess).

Comment: @AkashdeepSaluja How would you even parse 10^100 digits?

Comment: @AkashdeepSaluja: Do you need to store it accurately?

Comment: @irrelephant i didn't get you, could you be please more detailed about your query.

Comment: @NeilG i think as per the problem statement, may be i misunderstood, but without storing it accurately how can i compute accurately? Can I?

Comment: @AkashdeepSaluja What is 9025678901387192837981273 / 3009123897192 to 2 decimal places?

Comment: 2.99e12 that i got using c program, but using windows calculator 2999437447494.14

Comment: @AkashdeepSaluja: No. I only asked for two decimal places.  Do it without using a calculator.